# Image doesn't fit bootstrap jumbotron, wraps around

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am pretty sure this a common problem but I couldn't find any thing on this. Maybe I am not searching for the right thing.

So basically my problem is I place an `image` inside a `jumbotron div` and as the `image` is not wide enough, it `wraps` around and starts repeating itself. I tried to make the `image` wider in `Photoshop` however it reduces the `quality`. Is there an easy solution to this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, if the image is a certain size and that size is too small for what you need it for, there's no way to increase the size without distorting the resolution.

The general rule is that images can be made smaller, but quality goes down the larger you stretch it from it's original size.

Comment: Thanks a lot man. That is what I though. I think I can add similar images tail to head to get it to a certain width without distorting the details. Thanks again =)